# How to plot LogLinear and Loglog curve to the same plot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I wanted to plot linear-linear, log-linear, linear-log and log-log regression to my seaborn charts without transforming the values of the variable.

I am getting result for linear-linear, linear-log and even order 2. But could you please help me with log-log , log-linear along wih legends

```
ax = sns.regplot(x=X, y=y,ci=None)
ax = sns.regplot(x=X, y=y,ci=None,logx=True)
ax = sns.regplot(x=X, y=y,ci=None,order=2)
ax = sns.regplot(x=X, y=y,ci=None,order=3)
```

The chart looks like below
[image]

Thank you

Comment: The four lines of code you provide are of no use to readers unless you provide them X and Y. This makes answering your question with a working answer extremely difficult. Also, you need to include details like how your final plot should like like (at least some sample image even if hand sketched sometimes help).

Comment: I have shared the chart but unfortunately I cannot share the data..

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib `axes` for this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# log-log
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
sns.regplot(x=X, y=y, ci=None, ax=ax)
# log-linear
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xscale='linear', yscale='log')
sns.regplot(x=X, y=y, ci=None, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I want everything in one plot diagram. Could you please help me in that? If I change the axis then the graph gets changed for everything

Comment: In that case you probably need to transform the data before and then just plot via seaborn.

Comment: But If I transform, then again it wont come in the same plot right ?